# How do I add interactive videos on websites?

Tags: web, web-applications, video-streaming, frontend

I am creating a low budget web app (flask/jquery/bootstrap) with lecture videos. I want the videos to pause in certain moments and let the user answer a question (like on coursera or udacity). Later on I want to have access to the users answers in the backend. What is the best tool to accomplish this?

Comment: All you have to do is pause the video element with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, however in my question I also mentioned displaying a question on top of the paused movie, how can I achieve this?

Comment: You didn't mention displaying anything on top of a paused movie, but in any case, all you have to do for that is use the appropriate CSS to put your <video> behind other elements, or to put your other elements on top of the <video>.  I'd show you a specific way, but you provided no existing code to go off of.

Comment: Ok, that would be great, say that somewhere in my html I have a youtube video: inline`<div id='video'> <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kjPTQLgGpq8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> </div>` and after 15 mins. I want to ask a question: inline`<h1> how do you like the playlist so far? </h1> <form> <input type="radio" name="question" value="poor" checked>Poor<br> <input type="radio" name="question" value="good">Good<br>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
 </form>
`

Comment: I posted a more precise question with some code to go of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306214/pause-youtube-video-and-show-div-with-a-form